# How can I add two timeseries-matrices?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I got two datafields (df_A and df_B) that I want to combine to one datafield (df_total), but I only get NaNs! What to do?

```
print(df_A)

DATE           OILd      GOLD   US-RUSS
2000-01-31  0.073370 -0.026818  0.000099
2000-02-29  0.105606  0.038686  0.165135
2000-03-31 -0.121361 -0.061565 -0.065931
2000-04-30 -0.042815 -0.000181 -0.060177

print(df_B)
            OILm      COMM
DATE                          
2000-01-31  0.078671  0.037987
2000-02-29  0.020197  0.008202
2000-03-31 -0.133824 -0.059894
2000-04-30  0.108403  0.066403

df_total=df_A+df_B
print(df_total)

            COMM  GOLD  OILd  OILm  US-RUSS
2000-01-31   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
2000-02-29   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
2000-03-31   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
2000-04-30   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` with argument `axis=1`

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2]],
                   columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['c', 3], ['d', 4]],
                   columns=['C', 'D'])
print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
```

---

**df1:**

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
```

**df2:**

```
   C  D
0  c  3
1  d  4
```

---

**output:**

```
   A  B  C  D
0  a  1  c  3
1  b  2  d  4
```

so in your case you have to write it like

```
df_total = pd.concat([df_A, df_B], axis=1)
```

you can check the [Pandas documentation here for concat method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)

---

**Also you can do it using merge**

```
print(df_A)

DATE           OILd      GOLD   US-RUSS
2000-01-31  0.073370 -0.026818  0.000099
2000-02-29  0.105606  0.038686  0.165135
2000-03-31 -0.121361 -0.061565 -0.065931
2000-04-30 -0.042815 -0.000181 -0.060177

print(df_B)
            OILm      COMM
DATE                          
2000-01-31  0.078671  0.037987
2000-02-29  0.020197  0.008202
2000-03-31 -0.133824 -0.059894
2000-04-30  0.108403  0.066403
```

you have `DATE` column is common in both df

`print(df_A.merge(df_B, on='DATE', how='outer'))`

will give you desire result

Comment: Thanks Nihal, it solved my problem. :-) Sorry for late respons!